# Первая запись сохраняется последующие нет

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Как правильно вызвать сохранение в цикле?
Проблема в асинхронных вызовах. Нужно как то вызывать функцию сохранения в цикле после того как пришёл ответ от сервера. Или проблема в чём то другом

```
 service.prototype.save = function (menu_id, callback) {
        var that = this;
        angular.forEach(this.permissions, function (value, key) {
            if (value) {
                that.newItem.menu_id = menu_id;
                that.newItem.permission_id = key;
                console.log(that.newItem);
                that.resource.save({action: that.action}, that.newItem, function (data) {
                    console.log(typeof data);
                    console.log(data);
                   // that.items.push(data);
                    that.newItem = {
                        action: that.action
                    };
                    that.permissions = [];
                    if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                        callback(data);
                    }
                });
            }

        });

    };
```

**Вот так работает:**

```
service.prototype.save = function (menu_id, callback) {
    var that = this;
    angular.forEach(this.permissions, function (value, key) {
        if (value) {
            $timeout(function () {
                that.newItem.menu_id = menu_id;
                that.newItem.permission_id = key;
                console.log(that.newItem);
                that.resource.save({action: that.action}, that.newItem, function (data) {
                    console.log(typeof data);
                    console.log(data);
                    // that.items.push(data);
                    that.newItem = {
                        action: that.action
                    };
                    that.permissions = [];
                    if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                        callback(data);
                    }
                });
            }, 1000 * key);
        }
    });
};
```

Ошибка:

> data: "
> ↵**Notice**:  Undefined index: error in
>   **C:\server\OpenServer\domains\REST\resource\index.php** on line
>   **116**↵{"msg":[],"post":{"action":"MenuPerm","menu_id":"97","permission_id":"2"},"error":"PDOException:
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '97-2' for key 'test2'\n
>   File=C:\server\OpenServer\domains\REST\resource\index.php\n
>   Line=105\n#0 [internal function]: PDOStatement->execute()\n#1
>   [internal function]:
>   Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo->executePrepared(Object(PDOStatement),
>   Array, Array)\n#2 [internal function]:
>   Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo->execute('INSERT INTO `me...', Array,
>   Array)\n#3 [internal function]:
>   Phalcon\Db\Adapter->insert('menu_perm', Array, Array, Array)\n#4
>   [internal function]:
>   Phalcon\Mvc\Model->_doLowInsert(Object(Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData\Memory),
>   Object(Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql), 'menu_perm', 'id')\n#5
>   C:\server\OpenServer\domains\REST\resource\index.php(105):
>   Phalcon\Mvc\Model->save()\n#6 [internal function]:
>   {closure}('MenuPerm')\n#7
>   C:\server\OpenServer\domains\REST\resource\index.php(204):
>   Phalcon\Mvc\Micro->handle()\n#8 {main}"}"

```
CREATE TABLE likemyjob.menu_perm (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  menu_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  permission_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE INDEX test2 (menu_id, permission_id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_menu_perm_menu_id FOREIGN KEY (menu_id)
  REFERENCES likemyjob.menu (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT FK_menu_perm_permission_id FOREIGN KEY (permission_id)
  REFERENCES likemyjob.permission (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 105
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 682
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Попробовал сделать так результат тот же:

```
 service.prototype.save = function (menu_id, callback) {
        var that = this;
        angular.forEach(this.permissions, function (value, key) {
            if (value) {

                that.newItem.menu_id = menu_id;
                that.newItem.permission_id = key;
                that.helpSave(that.newItem);

            }
        });
    };

    service.prototype.helpSave = function (newItem) {
        console.log(newItem);
        var url = "/resource/source/MenuPerm";
        $http.post(url, newItem).
        then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }.bind(this), function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    };
```

Comment: можете описать словами что именно не работает?

Comment: @Grundy Я написал как работает и как не работает, если в таймере поставить 0 то тоже работает. А так словами написано данные не сохраняются в Mysql на той стороне их принимает Phalcon REST API

Comment: _,"error":"PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '97-2' for key 'test2'\n_

Comment: Ошибка на серверной стороне, потому что пытались вставить дубликат, а из вопроса, до обновления выходило, что скорее что-то с клиентом было, и было непонятно что именно

Comment: На самом деле с клиентом menu_id и menu_id Имеют ключ уникальный, если через таймер даже нулевой то всё ок

Comment: Но согласитесь, что ошибка базы говорит об обратном

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть какие запросы шлет ангуляр в первом случае

Comment: Ошибка базы говорит о том что данные приходят одинаковые, тоесть menu_id и permission_id ид на js скорее все получают указатели, и на момент формирования запроса к серверу цикл считается отработанным, на сервер попадает только последний элемент массива, по ощущениям, да проверил в Network так и есть

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34303/discussion-between-grundy-and-serge-esmanovich).

Answer (score 1):

В общем работает вот так, проблема была в указателях

```
   service.prototype.save = function (menu_id, callback) {
        var that = this;
        angular.forEach(this.permissions, function (value, key) {
            if (value) {
                that.helpSave(menu_id, key);
            }
        });
    };

    service.prototype.helpSave = function (menu_id, permission_id) {
        var newItem = {
            action: this.action,
            menu_id: menu_id,
            permission_id: permission_id
        };
        console.log(newItem);
        var test = newItem;
        var url = "/resource/source/MenuPerm";
        $http.post(url, test).
        then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }.bind(this), function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    };
```

Или вот так:

```
service.prototype.save = function (menu_id, callback) {
    var that = this;
    angular.forEach(this.permissions, function (value, key) {
        if (value) {
            var newItem = {
                action: this.action,
                menu_id: menu_id,
                permission_id: key
            };

            that.resource.save({action: that.action}, newItem, function (data) {
                console.log(typeof data);
                console.log(data);
                // that.items.push(data);
                that.newItem = {
                    action: that.action
                };
                that.permissions = [];
                if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                    callback(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Можно ещё помаятся с  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)); для клонирования